# CORS policy in node.js doesn't update headers

Tags: node.js, cors

I have two websites build in angular, one in the main domain and another in a subdomain. Both of these applications interact with a node.js application. The node.js app is using the cors package allowing requests from both urls, the problem is if i am in the subdomain and access some routes from the main domain app i get the cors blocked error but the origin i am receiving is the subdomain one (apparently). This also happens the other way around.

Example:
I access example.com/xyz and it works, then i go to the subdomain asd.example.com and get the cors error because the origin it receives is example.com.
Then if i clean the cache i can access asd.example.com but then i have the error on some routes in example.com and in this case the origin is asd.example.com.

One of the routes i have on the main application has the same name as the subdomain, is there any chance the issue is caused by this?

[edited]

This is my node.js cors code.
The `allowedOrigins` variable is an array with all allowed urls, e.g `var allowedOrigins = ['https://example.pt', 'https://www.example.pt', 'https://asd.example.pt'];`

```
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: function(origin, callback){
    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1){
      var msg = 'Blocked by CORS';
      console.log(msg);
      return callback(new Error(msg), false);
    }
    return callback(null, true);
  }
}));
```

Regarding my initial question i have already tried to change the subdomain name to something different than any route in main app.

Comment: Could you show you server code for the CORS implementation?

Comment: @SylvainF i have edited my question with my CORS implementation